# How do I handle missings with Full Information Maximum Likelihood in R?

Tags: r, regression, missing-data

I'm using R to perform a hierarchical multiple regression. To handle the missing values in my dataset, I'm supposed to use the Full Information Maximum Likelihood technique. I already looked at dozens of websites but I still can't figure out how to do it in R. 
I know that that I can use the 'sem' function of the lavaan package for my regression models, e.g. 
model <- sem('outcome ~ control variable 1 + control variable 2 + predictor of interest', data = df, missing = 'fiml', fixed.x = F). 
That seems to work. But I still need to compute descriptive statistics for variables that include missings. Thus, while I can calculate the regression models using FIML, I can't get e.g. the mean score of the variables due to the missings. Is there a way to apply FIML to all missings and change the dataset, so that the estimations replace the NA's? Or is there any other way to use FIML?

Thanks in advance!